# CocoaSecurity default AES Encryption key for SHA512?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, encryption, aes

I want to use `SHA512` hashing in CocoaSecurity Library here: https://github.com/kelp404/CocoaSecurity

As they are explaining in the library that the `default AES Encrypt`for SHA384 is:

```
key -> SHA384(key).sub(0, 32)

iv -> SHA384(key).sub(32, 16)
```

But if i need to use SHA512 What should be the `key` and `iv` ?

Comment: The way you've asked this question makes little sense. SHA-512 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hash. And the output of SHA-512 is too large for any version of AES, so you're going to have to truncate it somehow (as they're doing in CryptoSecurity). What exact encryption format are you trying to match? (Note that the default CryptoSecurity password encryption algorithm is very insecure, so shouldn't be emulated if you have a choice.)

Comment: Well so if  need to increase the size instead of using 0,32 or 32,16 is that supposed to be stronger by increasing the size ? and is there is good and secure way to use strong encryption algorithm ? i want to store Strings encrypted and then when i want it then i can decrypt it !

Comment: Can i say like : 0,128 for key  and 128,64 for iv ? does it makes the key stronger ?

Comment: Taking a human-provided string and running it through SHA-512 one time will never create strong encryption, no matter how many bits you take. The number of bits in the IV is not modifiable. If you're not trying to match an existing format, then I provide one intended to make it simple: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor. But if you're not trying to match an existing format, why are you trying to use SHA-512 rather than SHA-384 (you get no significant security that way)?

Comment: The problem is that human provided strings are easily guessed, so applying a fast, 1:1 algorithm to them like SHA provides very little security without doing other things (called salting and stretching). If your string is not human-provided; if it's actually completely random and unique for every encryption, then you don't need SHA at all.